# Regex To Parse Int and String

Tags: c#, regex

So I created this regex to parse strings like this (I need the values for Byte and Time):

```
1463735418    Bytes: 0    Time: 4.297
```

This is the code below (used [this](http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3))

```
string writePath = @"C:\final.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\union.dat");
foreach (string txt in lines)
{

    string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
    string re2 = "\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
    string re3 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
    string re4 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
    string re5 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
    string re6 = "([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";    // Float 1

    Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match m = r.Match(txt);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        String int1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
        String float1 = m.Groups[2].ToString();
        Debug.Write("(" + int1.ToString() + ")" + "(" + float1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
        File.AppendAllText(writePath, int1.ToString() + ", " + float1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

    }
}
```

This works perfectly when the string is represented as a line, however when I try to read my file which is like this .

```
1463735418
Bytes: 0
Time: 4.297
1463735424
Time: 2.205
1466413696
Time: 2.225
1466413699
1466413702
1466413705
1466413708
1466413711
1466413714
1466413717
1466413720
Bytes: 7037
Time: 59.320
... (arbritrary repition)
```

I get garbage data.

```
Expected Output: 
0, 4.297 
7037, 59.320
```

(match only where time-bytes pair exist)

Edit: I am trying something like this, but still I don't get the desired result.

```
foreach (string txt in lines)
            {

                if (txt.StartsWith("Byte"))
                {
                    string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
                    string re2 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1

                    Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    Match m = r.Match(txt);
                    if (m.Success)
                    {
                        String int1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
                        //Console.Write("(" + int1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
                        httpTable += int1.ToString() + ",";
                    }
                }
                if (txt.StartsWith("Time"))
                {
                    string re3 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
                    string re4 = "([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";    // Float 1

                    Regex r1 = new Regex(re3 + re4, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    Match m1 = r1.Match(txt);
                    if (m1.Success)
                    {
                        String float1 = m1.Groups[1].ToString();
                        //Console.Write("(" + float1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
                        httpTable += float1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }

            }
```

How can I mend it?
Thanks.

Comment: This input does not fit the existing pattern. What is the expected output for this one?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added expected output

Comment: Use Harry Potter's idea, and since bytes come before time, use a flag to reset after finding the whole pair.

Comment: Or, if you read the file contents with `.ReadToEnd()` you could use [`Bytes:\s*(?<bytes>\d+)\s*Time:\s*(?<time>\d+\.\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Bytes%3a%5cs*(%3f%3cbytes%3e%5cd%2b)%5cs*Time%3a%5cs*(%3f%3ctime%3e%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b)&i=1463735418%0d%0aBytes%3a+0%0d%0aTime%3a+4.297%0d%0a1463735424%0d%0aTime%3a+2.205%0d%0a1466413696%0d%0aTime%3a+2.225%0d%0a1466413699%0d%0a1466413702%0d%0a1466413705%0d%0a1466413708%0d%0a1466413711%0d%0a1466413714%0d%0a1466413717%0d%0a1466413720%0d%0aBytes%3a+7037%0d%0aTime%3a+59.320). It depends on how big the files are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that a lookbehind qualifies the time and bytes and if not found defaults into the integer category. Then by using regex named captures determine what has been found for each match.

```
string data = "1463735418 Bytes: 0 Time: 4.297 1463735424 Time: 2.205 1466413696 Time: 2.225 1466413699 1466413702 1466413705 1466413708 1466413711 1466413714 1466413717 1466413720 Bytes: 7037 Time: 59.320";

string pattern = @"
    (?<=Bytes:\s)(?<Bytes>\d+)   # Lookbehind for the bytes
    |                            # Or
    (?<=Time:\s)(?<Time>[\d.]+)  # Lookbehind for time
    |                            # Or
    (?<Integer>\d+)              # most likely its just an integer.
    ";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new
                   {
                       IsInteger = mt.Groups["Integer"].Success,
                       IsTime = mt.Groups["Time"].Success,
                       IsByte = mt.Groups["Bytes"].Success,
                       strMatch = mt.Groups[0].Value,
                       AsInt  = mt.Groups["Integer"].Success ? int.Parse(mt.Groups["Integer"].Value) : -1,
                       AsByte = mt.Groups["Bytes"].Success ? int.Parse(mt.Groups["Bytes"].Value) : -1,
                       AsTime = mt.Groups["Time"].Success ? double.Parse(mt.Groups["Time"].Value) : -1.0,
                   })
```

Here is the result which are an IEnumerable of each match as a dynamic entity with three `IsA`s and their corresponding `As` converted values if viable:

[image]

Comment: You do not need lookbehinds here. `(?<=Bytes:\s)` can be replaced with `Bytes:\s` as only the named captures will be used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good thought...I wanted to *play it safe* in case the OP had some condition he wasn't mentioning.

Comment: thats some complicated code! Thanks a lot. How do I access `mt` to write my file? I am really bad with `LINQ`
Thanks.

Comment: @jeet you are not accessing `mt` because the `Select` has *projected* it, into an array of dynamic entities away from the mt. Debug the program in a console app and look at the result when assigned `var theResult = Regex.Matches...`.

Comment: Thanks. Any easy way to print this `IEnum`?

Comment: @jeet One doesn't have to use the `IEnumerable<T>` that I have shown as a result in the example, one can loop through the matches with a for loop if Linq is not their forte. I just wanted to show all permutations of the results by putting it into a dynamic entity to view. When you say *print* if you mean debug and work with it, I use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) with the upgraded intellsense, that is what the print screen example is from.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on LinqPad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need values for `Bytes: ...` and `Time: ...`, use the exact strings, instead of fillers:

### For capturing `Bytes`

```
Bytes: (\d+)
```

### For capturing `Time`

```
Time: ([-+]\d*\.\d+)
```

### Generic pattern to capture both

```
(Bytes|Time): (\d+|[-+]\d*\.\d+)
```

Comment: Thanks you. I added the expected output in the question, sorry forgot to add it before. Does the Generic pattern match with it?

Comment: Without adding more logic to the code, this won't work since currently the file is read into a line array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added some logic and updated the question still, I am unable to construct a logic to leave `Byte-less` Time entries.